# FB.ui send Send dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an iframe which contains the link as shown below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="FB.ui({method: 'send', picture: pic, name: name, description : description , to: [xxxxxxxxxx],link:'http://link.com'}, function(response) {if (response) {alert('cool!')}})>Click me</a>
```

Any idea about how to make the FB.ui send dialog pop not in the iframe but in the parent window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'display mode' for FB.ui ,set it to what you want.For more details check,
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display

Comment: You are the best. The popup value actually did the trick. Thanks!